# Find Google Analytics object in window in conjunction with gatsby-plugin-google-analytics

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, gatsby

I'm trying to set up [event tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#overview) with Google Analytics. I am using Gatsby and `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics` in my `gatsby-config.js` to produce this Google Analytics snippet in the head of my document.

```
// gatsby-config.js
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics`,
  options: {
     trackingId: process.env.GA_TRACKING_CODE,
     head: true
  }
}
```

In the head of my document when viewing page source:

```
<link rel="preconnect dns-prefetch" href="https://www.google-analytics.com"/><script>

  if(!(navigator.doNotTrack == "1" || window.doNotTrack == "1")) {
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  }
  if (typeof ga === "function") {
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto', {}); // tracking code commented out         
  }
  </script>
```

Now according to the [Google Analytics docs on events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#overview), I can leverage the `analytics.js` script that gets loaded with the above script to send custom events to GA. Theoretically, I can use one React's `onClick` event on one of my components to fire a function that sends the required data.

Ex:

```
export default class Header extends React.Component {

    function trackCall() {
        ga('send', 'event', 'Call Us', 'call', 'Call Us')
    }

    render() {
        <button onClick={this.trackCall) href="tel:1234567890">Call Us</button>

}
```

The problem is that this code will give me a compilation error in gatsby: `error  'ga' is not defined  no-undef`. **I'm not sure how to define this correctly, e.i: get reference to the global GA object then call its methods**.

I know GA tracking is working on my site because I've tested it in real-time. However, when I scan the network resources in the console, I can't seem to find any reference to an analytics script or resource, so although it appears to be loading, perhaps the way it is bundled with gatsby and/or `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics` is loading it in a way that I'm not aware of.

Ideally, I want to load the GA script and then be able to access its methods to fire tracking events from my components.

I'm aware of `react-ga` and have looked at some examples but would prefer to implement this without additional packages.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and found the problem using the following...

Put the following into your gastby-config.js with your Google analytics id in the tracking ids

```
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-gtag`,
      options: {
        trackingIds: [
          "UA-XXXXXXXX-X"
        ],
        pluginConfig: {
          head: true,
        },
      },
```

and where you want to call `window.gtag` wrap it in an if defined like so

```
export default class Header extends React.Component {

    function trackCall() {
        if(window.gtag){
            window.gtag('send', 'event', 'Call Us', 'call', 'Call Us')
        }
    }

    render() {
        <button onClick={this.trackCall) href="tel:1234567890">Call Us</button>

}
```

Gatsby in develop mode will no longer complain and will ignore the code. Then if you use `gatsby build` and then `gatsby serve` you with GA Debug chrome extension you will see it added your tag to the dataLayer.